# Error when running android apps via bluestacks (Unsupported Device)

Tags: google-play-services, bluestacks

I run android apps using Bluestacks. I installed Clash of Clans android file and installed it and played it via Bluestacks. There is no problem playing the game. But when I want to sign in to my google account in clash of clans (*Setting › sing in to google*), this error appears:

> "Google Play services which some of your applications rely on is not
>   supported by your device. Please contact the manufacturer of your device".

Although I have Google Play Service installed on Bluestacks, this error appears again. Because I want to safeguard my progress in Clash of Clans, I must find a solution to this problem. I wanted to install Google Play Games, but the same error appeared. Please help me, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

you need Download `Google Play Service` Based on your Device ***DPI***,

Supported DPI'S :

[image]

Also, you can Install [CPU-Z](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cpuid.cpu_z&hl=en) Then, look at this section :
for example, look at the `Screen Density` on below picture :
[image]

as we can see on above picture, this picture have `560DPI`.

and then, you need Google Play service For `560DPI`.(for Example )